# Accessibility - Build Testing [ junit, etc.]

Tags: accessibility

Are there any tools out there that can do automated testing ( against WCAG guidelines) during a build process ( potentially utilizing somehting like junit, etc.)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a purely technical implementation question that should be on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a tool called aXe. It is a JavaScript library that can be used with any browser-based testing framework.

Here is a video on getting started https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy7Of9WO5JM

This is the link to the GitHub repo https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core

If you are using JUnit, here is the link to the Java-Selenium wrapper https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-selenium-java

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also check Google Accessibility developer tools: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/accessibility-developer-tools

Coverage is not that great, but you have several automated tests that run in a Phantom browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Continuum](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005922626-Overview-Access-Continuum) offers an SDK and several example projects that can be used to perform automated accessibility testing. For instance, here's some [documentation about how to use the Java/Cucumber/Selenium example project](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001054023-Continuum-for-Java-Cucumber-Selenium-), which might be a great starting point for you given you've expressed interest in using something like JUnit. Given there's not a specific JUnit example project for Continuum at the moment, here's [some API documentation](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005923506-Access-Continuum-APIs) that you could feasibly use to roll your own implementation of Continuum if you'd rather do that instead.